# how to get value of multiple textboxes in table column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am stuck with my project. On my `jsp` page, I've a `html table`. One column i.e. `addresses` has  multiple `textboxes` with values. Last column has a link named `edit`.

What I want: on click of edit I want values of addresses separated by commas.

What I did (onClick edit):

```
var values = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type=text]').val();
```

What I get : only one value (not other textfield values)

What I want(example) : newyork, washington. (if there were 2 textboxes with newyork and washington as address values in `addresses` column)

[image]

Comment: add more of your code please

Comment: try siblings instead of closest  $(this).siblings('tr').find('[type=text]').val();

Comment: Provide a [mcve] .

Comment: I have provided a image of what I want

Comment: @JSK, Check the answers

Answer (score 0):

Accoring to http://api.jquery.com/val/ val() returns only the first value. If you want all of them, you need to iterate such as:

```
var s = []; 
$(this).closest('tr').find('[type=text]').each(function(v) { 
    s.push(v.val());
})
```

P.S. Array.prototype.map could be useful here

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of all the inputs you can use the `map` function to go over all of the inputs and then the `get` function to get all the values into an array:

```js
var values = $('[type=text]').map(function() {
  return $(this).val();
}).get();
console.log(values);
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="a" value="a - val" />
<input type="text" name="b" value="b - val" />
```

Your code should look something like that:

```
var values = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type=text]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
}).get();
```

And a better example after you added the image of your table:

```js
$('#a1').click(function() {
  var values = $(this).closest('tr').find('[type=text]').map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  alert(values);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="a" value="a - val" />
      <input type="text" name="b" value="b - val" />
    </td><td>
      <div id="a1">edit</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: what exactly isn't working? where did you add it? what do you expect to work?

Comment: this code will give you an array of all the values of `input type="text"` that exists inside the `tr`.

Comment: how about if there are multiple `input type="text"` in different columns in single row

Comment: 1. According to your question - my answer is correct. If the question is not what you asked - it's hard to help. 2. If there are multiple inputs - you need to know how/which of them to include/exclude based on something (id/class/position/etc..)